# Flutter plugins for foreground tasks on Android and iOS

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm building a Flutter timer & stopwatch app. The app will have multiple stopwatches and timers. I want stopwatches and timers keep running when the app is closed. After doing some research I found that
what I'm looking for could be implemented with foreground services in Android. Searched for plugins to implement foreground services both on Android and iOS, but can't decide which plugin is more universal. Has anybody built feature similar to what I'm trying to build?
Which plugins would you recommend?

Comment: Can you explain your question? You need to timer plugin with prepared UI or just timer without interface?

Comment: Hi @fartem , I have updated the question, have a look please, thanks.

Comment: If you have a specific features for app and it is mapping to native side, maybe create a foreground services from scratch is the best way.